# Backing up an entire drive

Tags: backup

How do I back up an entire drive (all partitions and everything
outside of partitions)?  Do I make a dedicated backup partition
on the target drive (how?) or do I make a larger partition and
file system, and back up to a huge file?

Comment: Did you have a look at clonezilla?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you explicitly ask for a file or a partition being the target but not an entire disk?

Comment: dd+zip save as file

Comment: @Hermann, yes, I don't want to spend an entire drive on a backup that's smaller than the drive.  I want to back up an SSD of 300GB, but my external drives are bigger than that.

Comment: Are you sure about backing up the entire partitions? Unused space may contain a lot of entropy and make the backup a lot bigger than it needs to be

Comment: I agree with @Hermann: Make an image of the whole drive with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org). It is smart enough to only copy used blocks (and skip free space in the file systems). It also uses compression.

Comment: @Toothrot Is the drive always online (in a running system) or offline (e.g. an external hard-drive)? Is an operating system installed on the drive or is it "just data"? What filesystems are involved?